# How to use onBeforeRouteLeave in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxt and I am not able to find how to use onBeforeRouteLeave in Nuxt with composition API

If possible to give me an example it will be great Thanks

Comment: As in a regular vue app: https://search.brave.com/search?q=vue-router+onBeforeRouteLeave+composition+api&source=web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuxt 3 uses Vue Router for routing. The documentation goes over onBeforeRouteLeave [Here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/index.html#onbeforerouteleave).

OnBeforeRouteLeave acts as a guard to prevent a page from leaving before a task is completed. Heres an example of how it could be used that you may be familiar with!

```
onBeforeRouteLeave (to, from) {
  const answer = window.confirm('Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!')
  if (!answer) return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { onBeforeRouteLeave } from "vue-router"; (optional)

// import the method from the vue-router to avoid error mark if you're making use of eslint or typescript

onBeforeRouteLeave((to, from, next) => {
  const answer = window.confirm(
    "Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!"
  );

  if (!answer) return false;
  // return false cancel the route change
  next()
});
```